# IMessenger.Send Missing Overload That Accepts a Token

Tags: mvvm-light

Not sure if this was a design decision but IMessenger.Send seems to be missing overload that accepts a token

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by "token" you mean a string that identifies something about the message, there are several things you can do.

1. You can use the NotificationMessage class as the message you're sending.

   ```
   Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("Token"));
   ```
2. If you want to use something other than a string as a token, you can use NotificationMessage.

   ```
   Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage<IToken>(new Token()));
   ```
3. You can create your own message class and use it. This lets you register for only messages of your custom type. **This is what I recommend.**

   ```
   public class ErrorMessage : GenericMessage<Exception>
   {
       public ErrorMessage(Exception content) : base(content)
       {
       }
       public ErrorMessage(object sender, Exception content) : base(sender, content)
       {
       }
       public ErrorMessage(object sender, object target, Exception content) : base(sender, target, content)
       {
       }
   }
   ```